# How to configure the Apache Sever in ubuntu to run sites locally?

Tags: apache, ubuntu, virtualhost

I am new to Apache and I want to configure example.com remotely. I do not own that domain. I tried this https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-set-up-apache-virtual-hosts-on-ubuntu-14-04-lts
but it didn't work. Can someone tell me what should be the contents of my example.conf file so that example.com and www.example.com both should point at my localhost. thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this entry in your /etc/hosts file

```
127.0.0.1 example.com
127.0.0.1 www.example.com
```

Then try to hit the URL from the Browser.

Comment: can you please tell me the code for example.com.conf so that any user on my local machine can access example.com and www.example.com